# SwiftUI squared image in a circle

Tags: swiftui

I try to draw a squared `Image` inside of a `Circle` to get something like that (without blue square here. It is just to show image squared border):

[image: squared Image in a Circle]

This code makes squared image over all circle.

```
ZStack() {
    Circle()
        .fill(.orange)
        
    Image(systemName: "trash")
        .resizable()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .background(.orange)
}
```

This code makes a small image on the circle or no circle at all:

```
ZStack() {
    Circle()
        .fill(.orange)
        
    Image(systemName: "trash")
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .background(.orange)
}
```

I try to find a solution to have squared image **inside** the circle. It should not goes outside of it.
Maybe, I would also need a small margin between image and circle's border.

Is there a way to do that easily? Or I have to use math to get circle border or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asperi just beat me to it, but this view will just take an icon name and a radius and return a squared icon perfectly in a circle:

[image]

```
struct ImageOnCircle: View {
    
    let icon: String
    let radius: CGFloat
    var squareSide: CGFloat {
        2.0.squareRoot() * radius
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(.orange)
                .frame(width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
            Image(systemName: icon)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: squareSide, height: squareSide)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
ImageOnCircle(icon: "trash", radius: 150)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly! I've added a `shadow` on `Circle()` and, of course, changed colors to get something prettier. It is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Just a little something: You can remove `1.0, ` in `aspectRatio` to keep image original ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo of possible approach - use overlay + geometry reader to calculate internal rectangle where image is injected.

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15 (blue rect is of Preview one for selected image)

[image: demo]

```
Circle()
    .fill(.orange)
    .overlay(GeometryReader {
        let side = sqrt($0.size.width * $0.size.width / 2)
        VStack {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.clear)
                .frame(width: side, height: side)
                .overlay(
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .resizable()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                )
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    })
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works also really fine! But I couldn't add a shadow only on `Circle()` border.

Comment: @Jonathan: This answer is the right one! if you have issue about shadow ask in deferent question! He cannot answer multi question once your issue answered!

Comment: @swiftPunk sure! It was just a note about this answer, not another question.